# Workspaces Page Blue

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, workspaces

When i go onto the workspaces page on Ubuntu 11.10 the background images on the 4 viewable workspaces are all blue. I can still see running programs on the workspaces page. When I change to the workspaces to the one I want to go on it is very laggy and takes a while to load.

This is in Unity 2D.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Unity (or more likely, Compiz) has gone funky. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the run dialog, then enter `unity --replace`. This will restart 
Unity and should clear things up for you.

Comment: This fixes up the problem but after I restart my computer it is back to the usual blue screen. Is there a way to make this permanent or to run the command when I log in? I tried to add the command to startup applications but this doesn't work.

Comment: @11chubby11: The permanent solution is to find out why this is happening. I'm not sure how to go about doing that, but I suspect that it's got something to do with your hardware exercising a bug in Compiz. The options I know of are: a) do this manually every time; or b) use another environment such as Gnome Shell. You can try starting Gnome Shell, and then having gnome-shell launch `unity --replace`, but I don't know whether that would work.

Comment: I have found out that this is only happening when I use unity 2d. When I went back to the normal unity the blue screen problem is not there.

Comment: @11chubby11: The fact that it's in Unity 2D is significant and should have been mentioned in the original question (I've edited it for you). My solution is based on the assumption of Unity 3D. 2D is a whole other ball of wax, and I don't know enough about it to help there.